# Strange bug with multibib

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, subdividing, multibib

Could someone help me with multibib? On windows machine with texlive 2011 installed the following file hangs during compilation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{pub}{Publications}
\newcites{con}{Conferences}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Of course, it is a minimal not-working example and it is not very informative. But the error is the same and this latex file is supposed to be correct. The compilation stops at the following lines:

```
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multibib/multibib.sty) (./pub.aux)
(./con.aux
```

It just stops. If I do ctrl+c I see the following:

```
! Interruption.
<argument> ...@auxout\@suffix name\endcsname .aux}
                                                  \endgroup \immediate \open...
l.5 \newcites{con}{Conferences}

?
```

I have no idea where this problem comes from. I have tried to google, but it seems that this error is not something well-known.

**UPD** It seems that it is a bug of texlive at windows. I would be hapy if someone gave me any clue how to find where exactly the problem occurs.

Comment: It compiles, for me.

Answer (score 4):

I've tested the following minimal example using `multibib` with TeX Live 2011 on Windows 7, and it works for me. The compilation steps were

> pdflatex test.tex bibtex test.aux  bibtex www.aux pdflatex test.tex

EDIT: It also works using latexmk.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib,url}
\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\newcites{www}{Weblinks}
\bibliographystylewww{plain}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{literatur.bib}
 @misc{test,
 author={Hans Hansi},
 title={Titel},
 year=1900,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{www.bib}
 @misc{test1,
 author={tex stackexchange},
 title={Strange bug with multibib},
 year=2011,
 howpublished={\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40743/strange-bug-with-multibib}}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\nocitewww{*}
\bibliography{literatur}
\bibliographywww{www}
\end{document}
```

[image]